# нажатие на ссылку увеличивает значение поля-инпута на 4

Tags: php, javascript, битрикс

Вопрос такой  у меня было поле, и две стрелки (вверх и вниз) которые увеличивают значение  поля на 1, уменьшает значение на 1. и оно работало. Приведу код

```html
<form action="<?=POST_FORM_ACTION_URI?>" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" class="add_form_to_basket">
        <div class="count clearfix"> 
         <?if($arParams["USE_PRODUCT_QUANTITY"]){
          $razn=$ar["AMOUNT"]-$quant;?>
          <div class="counter">
           <input type="text" class="counter_input" size="3" onblur="if (this.value &gt; <?=$razn;?>) this.value=<?=$razn;?>" 
           name="<?echo $arParams['PRODUCT_QUANTITY_VARIABLE']?>" value="1" id="<?echo $arParams['PRODUCT_QUANTITY_VARIABLE']?><?=$arElement["ID"];?>"> 
          </div>
          <div class="counter">
           <div class="quantity_control">
            <a class="PlusList plus" href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="if (BX('<?echo $arParams["PRODUCT_QUANTITY_VARIABLE"]?><?=$arElement["ID"]; ?>').value &lt; <?=$razn;?>) BX('<?echo $arParams["PRODUCT_QUANTITY_VARIABLE"]?><?=$arElement['ID']?>').value++;"></a>
            <a class="MinusList minus" href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="if (BX('<?echo $arParams["PRODUCT_QUANTITY_VARIABLE"]?><?=$arElement["ID"]; ?>').value &gt; 1) BX('<?echo $arParams["PRODUCT_QUANTITY_VARIABLE"]?><?=$arElement['ID']?>').value--;"></a> 
           </div>
          </div>
                                                                                <div class="counter">
                                                                                        
                                                                                        <input type="hidden" name="price" value="<?=$price?>">
                                                                                        <input type="hidden" name="xml_id" value="<?=$xml_id?>">
           <input type="submit" class="btn btn-small" onclick="if (<?=$razn?> &gt; 0){yaCounter12899284.reachGoal('CART'); return true;}else{this.disabled=true; return true;}" name="<?echo $arParams['ACTION_VARIABLE'].'ADD2BASKET'?>" value="" title="Добавить в корзину" id="link2card<?=$arElement['ID']?>">
          </div>
         <?}?>
        </div>
 </form>
```

И оно работало. А сейчас возникла необходимость введения кратности товара. Пусть кратность товара равна 4. Тогда в поле инпут должно стает первоначально значение 4. и Увеличивать надо значение на 4 и уменьшать на 4.  Вот у меня не работает `.value+4`.Вопрос: так делают вообще или нет.

```html
<a class="MinusList minus" href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="if (BX('<?echo $arParams["PRODUCT_QUANTITY_VARIABLE"]?><?=$arElement["ID"]; ?>').value &gt; 4) BX('<?echo $arParams["PRODUCT_QUANTITY_VARIABLE"]?><?=$arElement['ID']?>').value-4;"></a>
```

почему нельзя делать `.value-4` и не работает.

Comment: Пожалуйста, перечитайте свой вопрос еще раз. Вам самому-то понятно, о чем спрашиваете? Уточните, что вы пытаетесь сделать, что ожидаете на выходе и что получается.

Comment: Присоединяюсь к @VenZell в чем суть вопроса? Ну и от себя, при чем здесь битрикс (кроме его переменных), проблемы связанной именно с этой системой не вижу?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ловкость рук и никакого обмана. Берём ваш код, который вызывает ошибку (спойлер: смешную до ужаса):

```
BX('<?echo $arParams["PRODUCT_QUANTITY_VARIABLE"]?><?=$arElement['ID']?>').value-4;
```

Упростим:

```
BX('myName13').value-4;
```

Ещё упростим:

```
val-4
```

А теперь давайте решим задачу, что происходит, когда пишешь:

```
val-4
```

Что должно произойти? Во всяком случае, присваивания никакого не будет. Напишите «-=» и «+=» в соответствующий местах вот и всё.